# drawing plot for function with 2 arguments in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I need to draw a plot for the simple function defined on a interval.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

def sqr(x, n=2):
    return float(x ** n)

def get_plot(func, xs, n):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        ys.append(func(x, n))
        ys = np.array(ys)
    plt.plot(xs, ys)

xs = np.arange(1.0, 30., 0.01)
get_plot(sqr, xs, 4)
```

But it gives me typeError:

```
TypeError: get_plot() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Note that your function is called `get_ploat()`, not `get_plot()`, which is presumably defined somewhere else in your script and takes 2 arguments, in contrast to `get_ploat()` that takes 3

Comment: Maybe worth noting that your whole script can be simplified to two lines `xs = np.arange(1.0, 30., 0.01); 
plt.plot(xs, xs**4)`

Comment: thanks. I've edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the spelling mistake in the function name, you should convert your list to array outside the for loop once you are done appending all the functions. Moreover, I do not see why you are making the code so complicated when you can just use vectorised operation on your NumPy array `xs` as `ys=xs**4`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

def sqr(x, n=2):
    return float(x ** n)

def get_plot(func, xs, n):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        ys.append(func(x, n))
    ys = np.array(ys) # <-- moved outside the for loop
    plt.plot(xs, ys)

xs = np.arange(1.0, 30., 0.01)
get_plot(sqr, xs, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: actually, the function which i should draw, is more complex than introduced in example. So i can't just use xs ** 4.

Comment: @АлексСеркин: Ok, but anyway, my answer should solve the current problem of yours

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! May be you could help to adopt further? If I want to make a plot from function h(x), where h(x)=int(f(x)) how may I do it without retyping whole get_plot function?

Comment: I didn’t understand your question. Could you please elaborate